# Maven configuration in Anypoint studio /ESB Mule

Tags: maven, mule, anypoint-studio

I am new to Maven. I tried to install maven in existing Anypoint studio (version 6.0) by following below steps.

1) Help -> Install New software -> select the site -> lookfor maven -> click Next -> Install
2) Restarted the Anypoint studio.

Now i have try to create a mule project by enabling "Use Maven". But is disabled after maven add on installation. I have clicked "configure Maven" and it asked me the maven installation directory. I dont know what is maven installatin directory.

Windows -> Preference -> Anypoint studio->Maven->entered some path in the installation directory->
Error : Value must point to the root of maven installation[image].

Here I have attached error screenshot. Kindly help me in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download Maven from their [website](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi). Extract in the folder you want and reference it from Anypoint in that field
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPRF0.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to point it to one folder inside.like 
C:\apache-maven-3.5.0-bin\apache-maven-3.5.0 
/bin should be an immediate child to Maven Home

Regards, 
Amatya Annamaneni